# Imposing complex unique constraint in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint, oracle19c

I have following Oracle 19c table:

```
create table t (
  id number primary key,
  pid number not null,
  tech varchar2(1)
);
```

and I want to impose following constraint on columns `pid` and `tech`:

**Within group of records of same `pid`, following situations of `tech` values are not allowed:**

- **multiple same nonnull values**
- **multiple `null` values**
- **`null` and nonnull value**

In other words, for `null` value of `tech` there must not exist any other `null` or nonnull value. For nonnull value there must not exist other `null` or same value.

My questin is if this task is solvable using plain `unique index` or other simple database feature. Application-based guard is the fallback if other solutions are impossible or hard to understand.

### Test data

(with expected result of insertion of all rows of given `pid`, all testcases with pid<10 are succeeding, pid>=90 are failing)

```
with t(pid, tech) as (
  select 1  , null from dual union all
  select 2  , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 3  , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 3  , 'B'  from dual union all
  select 90 , null from dual union all
  select 90 , null from dual union all
  select 91 , 'A'  from dual union all  
  select 91 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 92 , null from dual union all  
  select 92 , null from dual union all  
  select 92 , 'A'  from dual union all  
  select 92 , 'B'  from dual union all
  select 93 , null from dual union all  
  select 93 , null from dual union all  
  select 93 , 'A'  from dual union all  
  select 93 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 94 , null from dual union all  
  select 94 , 'A'  from dual union all  
  select 94 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 95 , null from dual union all  
  select 95 , null from dual union all  
  select 95 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 96 , null from dual union all
  select 96 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 97 , null from dual union all
  select 97 , 'A'  from dual union all
  select 97 , 'B'  from dual
)
select pid--, count(distinct tech) as d, count(tech) as t, count(*) as c
     , case when count(*) = 1 or count(*) = count(tech) and count(*) = count(distinct tech) then 'OK' else 'ERROR' end as count_check
from t
group by pid
order by pid;
```

| PID | COUNT_CHECK |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | OK |
| 2 | OK |
| 3 | OK |
| 90 | ERROR |
| 91 | ERROR |
| 92 | ERROR |
| 93 | ERROR |
| 94 | ERROR |
| 95 | ERROR |
| 96 | ERROR |
| 97 | ERROR |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bIulB10C)

### Attempts

I have tried couple but with no or partial success:

- unique index based on auxiliary value ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H8qPSkdA)). The value is computed as virtual column (`vc`) so that `null`s are mapped to other nonnull existing value within group or to certainly-nonexistent value (which is not problem to set and rely on). Unique index is then imposed on the `(pid,vc)` tuple. In case of two `null`s or `null` together with nonnull, the uniqueness of such index would be violated. The problem is, the value of `vc` columns needs to be computed using function operating on same table and `ORA-04091: table is mutating` error appears on attempt of insert. (If window functions were allowed in virtual column expression the function would not be needed but unfortunately this is [not possible](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/want-to-use-analytical-function-as-a-virtual-column-6638).)
- table-scope constraint. Essentially what I need is no row with `count_check='ERROR'`  as defined by `count`s in test data sample. It would be great to impose such constraint on the table as a whole. I played with [solution](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=conditional-complex-constraint) based on materialized views but ran into privilege issues and two new db objects don't seem too convincing anyway.

Comment: you probably need a trigger

Comment: You cannot impose a constraint over more than one row. If you need that kind of complexity, you will have to use a trigger. But, I suggest that you reconsider your data model, as there's probably a better way to design so that such a complex constraint is not required. For example, why not go with the unique constraint to eliminate multiple values but allow the mix of NULL and distinct NOT NULL values to exist in the table, but at *query* time use SQL to prioritize the non-null values and ignore the NULL one?

Comment: do you really need to have the rows containing null?
if not, the thing sounds quite easy when negating your requirements:
it would be a simple unique on pid and tech, while "no row present at all" could be regarded as "null". But of cause the behavior of this is not exactly as you asked, because there is no "explicit null row" hindering addition of non-null rows :-/

Comment: Quoting my coworker who assigned me this problem: (quote)Thanks for the suggestions, but we really need to avoid inserting a row that violates the given rules (including null). Maybe implementation in trigger or table service PL/SQL package is the only solution. We are looking for a clean database solution. But your suggestions can help others who can make concessions with null values. (/unquote) My comment: insertion is invoked directly upon user action so allowing storage of nulls would force us immediately call check logic - user must get error on attempt of inserting illegal data.

Comment: I think it's clear that if you really need to do this, write a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was finally solved at application level. We made a decision that benefits of guarding constraint at lower level are no worth adding and maintaining new database object. Thank you all for advices. The answer to my question is simply *no*.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a materialized view with refresh fast on commit and put the constraint there, but the constraint will be check at COMMIT time only.
(+ the unique index on (pid,tech))

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON t
WITH rowid, primary key, COMMIT SCN, SEQUENCE
( pid, tech ) INCLUDING NEW VALUES
;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_t 
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT 
AS
SELECT pid, 
    count(case when tech is null then 1 end ) as c_null,
    count(case when tech is not null then 1 end) as c_notnull
FROM t 
GROUP BY pid
;


ALTER TABLE  mv_t 
ADD CONSTRAINT mv_ck_nulls CHECK ( 
    (c_null = 0 and c_notnull >= 0)
    or 
    (c_null = 1 and c_notnull = 0)
) ENABLE
;
```